# Communication technique which transforms our point of view by looking at the same situation from different perspectives

Tags: single-word-requests

How is it called a communication technique which transforms our point of view by looking at the same situation from different perspectives, as it is described in sentences below?

> “Your mother constantly interferes into your life.”
>
> “Your mother would like to thus protect you.”

Comment: Sorry but this not about the English language; certainly not linguistics. Could migrate.

Comment: @Kris - Could you clarify why this not ... ? Where might my question migrate?

Comment: To understand that, try asking the same Q. in another language -- any difference?  

You are likely find the right answers on literatureSE, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such communication technique is called *[spin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spin)*:

> To present, describe, or interpret, or to introduce a bias or slant so as to give something a favorable or advantageous appearance.  (eg) ... "In every administration there will be spokesmen and public affairs officers who try to spin the news to make the President look good."

Note that  "spinning" is indeed a technique intended to "transform our point of view"; it does so by putting forward the best possible interpretation from the speaker's point of view.  "Spinning" is a non-neutral term, in that it suggests the speaker's motives may be selfish.

A near-synonym is *[slant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slant)*:

> A bias, tendency, or leaning; a perspective or angle. (eg) It was a well written article, but it had a bit of a leftist slant.

Comment: Thank you. I have two little question. Could we say 'spinning' to refer to the technique? Do you think that the question have nothing to do with English language?

Comment: Umm, "spin" is normally understand to mean a manipulative technique for framing an idea in terms favorable to your side of a debate or disagreement. Like, "One of the leading members of our party has just been caught accepting a bribe. How can we spin this to not look so bad? Perhaps we can say ..." The term is not normally used for different points of view in cases that don't involve some sort of debate, almost always political debate.

Comment: @AngloSaxon,  (a) Re 'spinning', I added a paragraph in answer.  (b) Re "to do with English language", terminology and names of techniques seem to me to be questions about what words are appropriate. I don't understand Kris's comment.

Comment: @jwpat7 I cannot see the paragraph you had added in answer regarding 'spinning.' Thank for the comment.

Comment: @AngloSaxon, apparently my internet service was down - have re-sent the edit now

Answer (score 1):

I think the generic term is [implicature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature) - or in more common parlance, perhaps, the [subtext](http://www.answers.com/topic/subtext).

Either of OP's examples could be said in the same situation, but

In the first, the implication is the speaker thinks the addressee should take steps to stop his mother from taking so much interest in his affairs.

In the second, the speaker approves of the mother's position, and wants the addressee to also be favourably disposed to her involvement.

Answer (score 0):

I think in normal context this is simply called "point of view" or "viewpoint". As in, "Yes, I understand that you think your mother is interfering with your life, but you know, from her VIEWPOINT, she's trying to protect you." Or, "... from her POINT OF VIEW ...".